# Clarification on video about frequency deviation in phase modulation bandwidth

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, modulation, bandwidth

I am watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJWQibALuEc) video and at 7:12 he calculates the frequency deviation $\Delta f = f_{c}f_{m}A_{m} $ where the $c$ underscript is for "carrier" and the $m$ underscript is for "message".

But if you analyze it dimensionally the units dont match $\Delta f$ should be in Hz but $f_{c}$ and $f_{m}$ are in Hz and $A_{m}$ is dimensionless so on the one side we have Hz while on the other side we have Hz^{2}.What is going on?

Comment: that video isn't great. He acts very "oh yes these formulas are all very important", "the numbers are very large" (what makes a number large? They're not really.) but he doesn't really explain them. Basically, you need to understand the things before you watch this video, otherwise all you get is formulas that you are supposed to learn by heart, which will help you nowhere, because nobody needs you to know them by heart, but to understand them.

Comment: Anyway, I can't find your formula $\Delta f = f_{c}f_{m}A_{m} $  at all at 7:12. Are you sure about that timestamp? I'll also say that defining a frequency deviation for a phase modulator might not be very useful. What the video says is that $\Delta f = k_P V_m f_m$, but that's simply a different formula than you claim here.

Comment: Ah!You are correct.$K_{p}$ is the modulation sensitivity of the local oscillator which produces the carrier signal and it is measured in $Hz/V$ but we still have 2 Hz's in the nominator so what is going on?

Comment: "He acts very "oh yes these formulas are all very important", "the numbers are very large" (what makes a number large? They're not really.) but he doesn't really explain them. Basically, you need to understand the things before you watch this video, otherwise all you get is formulas that you are supposed to learn by heart, which will help you nowhere, because nobody needs you to know them by heart, but to understand them. "Angle modulation in the time domain gives $sin(sin(f(t))$.How can you Fourier transform this?Also I am trying to learn the basics.

Comment: $K_p$, as a sensitivity, should be 1/V here, not Hz/V.

Comment: (as said, I wouldn't recommend that video to learn the basics, but you seem to have different expectations! That's fine, it's just that there's too much "you need to know this formula" and too little "… and that's how you arrive at that formula: remember how this works, and you'll always be able to derive the formula yourself" in that video. For my taste.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice but for the test we only need to know the final formula not the derivation of it.

Comment: You need to decide whether you "want to learn the basics" or "only the final formula". These two concepts are mutually exclusive. Learning formulas by heart would be super frustrating to me. And if you weren't trying to *understand* these formulase, you wouldn't ask this question ;-)

Comment: Im trying to understand the DIMENSIONAL ANALYSIS of these formulas

Comment: yeah, well, then good luck. The right dimension for the formula symbols stem from their meaning, in which you're explicitly not interested!